# Javascript Countdown that loads ahref

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm totally a beginner with JavaScript and I'm trying to make a Javascript Countdown that loads an `<a href=""></a>`

I'm using this code for the countdown

```js
<script language="Javascript">

var countdown;
var countdown_number;

function countdown_init() {
    countdown_number = 11;
    countdown_trigger();
}

function countdown_trigger() {
    if(countdown_number > 0) {
        countdown_number--;
        document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
        if(countdown_number > 0) {
            countdown = setTimeout('countdown_trigger()', 1000);
        }
    }
}

function countdown_clear() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
}

</script>
```

I want to load exactly this `<a href="bgplayer-stop://"></a>` after the count reaches 0... I am totally lost... what should I do?

It is basically a countdown that stops a music player after reaching 0. I would like to set up several countdowns with 10 mins, 15 mins, and 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using mostly what you had above. This will need to be expanded a bit in order to have multiple countdowns but the general idea is here.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zp6nfc9b/5/

HTML:

```
<a id="link_to_click" href="bgplayer-stop://">link</a>
<span id="countdown_text"></span>
```

JS:

```
var countdown_number;
var countdown_text = document.getElementById('countdown_text');
var link_to_click = document.getElementById('link_to_click');

function countdown_init() {
    countdown_number = 11;
    countdown_trigger();
}

function countdown_trigger() {
    countdown_number--;
    countdown_text.innerHTML = countdown_number;
    if (countdown_number > 0) {
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                countdown_trigger();
            }, 1000
        );
    }
    else {
        link_to_click.click();
    }
}

link_to_click.addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        countdown_text.innerHTML = 'link was clicked after countdown';
    }
);

countdown_init();
```

To explain some portions a little I think overall you had the correct idea.

I only added the `eventListener` so you could see the link was actually being clicked and displays a message in the `countdown_text` for you.

You didn't need to check `countdown_number` more than once so I removed that if block.

Also you don't really need to clear the timeout either. It clears itself once it executes. You only really need to clear a timeout if you want to stop it before it completes but since we rely on the timeout completing in order to do the next step its not necessary.

Comment: This one doesn't fit what I'm looking for because it actually starts by itself on load, I want people to press, then the countdown starts and after countdown reaches 0 the action happens. Basically is a timer for a radio app. I'm trying to set up a timer function that stops the radio after a desired amount of time... Many thanks for the ideas!

Comment: It was an example. I was writing the entire scenario for you. I stated in the answer it would need to be modified to fit your scenario but this was the general idea. You can take that code and make it load whenever you want.

Comment: It's simple enough to change this to start how you want. If you need me to I can unless you already have a solution. Just let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yes, I need you ;) I don't know how to make it start after pressing a button and then after a specified amount of time simulate the click on <a href="bgplayer-stop://"></a> ... :( thanks

Comment: Thank you very much!! It was great this time, the thing is that the system that I'm using doesn't work with it because it opens the link in a new window, and it has to simulate a "tap" in the app not a full click that sends the user to another page... It's weird but it should generate something like a click & hold and not a full click & release... not working but closer to it, really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yea, click and hold is not a real event. That can be simulated I suppose. Is this like a mobile app with touch? Or something with like cordova?

Comment: I'm doing it through appsmoment.com that allows me to play with templates and that kind of stuff.. and I have similar buttons already in the app that play/stop a radio streaming like this: 
    <a id="streamlink" class="wpstartmenuTitle" href="bgplayer-play://http://13373.live.streamtheworld.com/CADENASER_SC" onclick="playa()">
     <img class="wpstartmenuImage" src="cadenaser.png" style="height: 65px; width: 150px;">
    </a>

Comment: And after pressed it shows the pause button <div id="stopa" style="display:none;">

    <a href="bgplayer-stop://" onclick="stopa()">

     <img class="wpstartmenuImage" src="pauseser.png" style="height: 65px; width: 150px;">

    </a>

   </div>

Comment: If pressed it pauses the thing.. So I'm trying to do a stop button that stops all sounds after a counter ends... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var countdown;
var countdown_number;

function countdown_init(time) {
    countdown_number = time;
    countdown_trigger();
}


function countdown_trigger() {
    if (countdown_number > 0) { 
        countdown_number--;
        document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
        setTimeout('countdown_trigger()', 1000)
    } else { // when reach 0sec
        stop_music()
    }
}

function stop_music(){ 
    window.location.href = "bgplayer-stop://"; //will redirect you automatically
}
```

Comment: This one doesn't work because apparently it loads in a new window the a href="bgplayer-stop://" and I need that option to be activated as pressing a button or a link... it only works like this <a href="bgplayer-stop://>Like this</a> Otherwise it tries to open a new window and that is not valid in the environment that I'm using... Many thanks for the help, it looks like it will work if it could be set as pressing a link or a button...